# Is there software or a web site that lets me upload a photo and visualize changes to a room?

Tags: bathroom, kitchens, software

I'm thinking of changing my kitchen and bath floor, countertops and backsplash.  I don't have all day to create a 3-D model from scratch.  Can I start with a photo and visualize changes?

Comment: Does it have to be free software?

Comment: or this one: http://www.3dkitchenplanners.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but I would suggest that you try [Autodesk Homestyler](http://www.homestyler.com/features).

An example in design mode

[image]

And a feature that renders your design into almost life like pictures!

[image]

Comment: really nice program. was looking for something like for ages

Answer (score 0):

http://floorplanner.com/

Loads of items, really easy to use (like "The Sims") lots of calculations and 3D rendering. Its free - only cost is for high definition pictures.

[image]